# "WHAT do you want to be?" vs "WHO do you want to be?"

Tags: difference, american-english, word-difference, pronouns, british-english

I came across this

> **What** do you want to be when you grow up?
>   [...]
>   Are you right now **who** you want to be?

and the first sentence sounds weird to my English learner's ear. Specifically, I am questioning why *what* was used instead of *who*.

> **What** do you want to be when you grow up?
>   **Who** do you want to be when you grow up?

I was taught that *what* usually doesn't refer to a human being.

Does it sound OK to you?
Is there any difference between the two?
Is there anything *what* puts emphasis on there?

[The author](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stephen_Covey) is an American.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"*What* do you want to be when you grow up" refers to the profession (doctor, teacher...), not to the person, so it is correct and sounds just fine.

The search (in quotes) in Google: ["What do you want to be when you grow up"](https://www.google.com/search?newwindow=1&ei=d97TXPXaGcHHwQKOq4vgAg&q=%22what+do+you+want+to+be+when+you+grow+up%22&oq=%22what+do+you+want+to+be+when+you+grow+up%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0l5j0i7i30j0l4.7724.8577..9306...0.0..0.80.565.9......0....1..gws-wiz.u8PLKl13kAE) gives 853,000 results, [site:uk](https://www.google.com/search?newwindow=1&ei=gd7TXICUIsnewAKU5bfwCQ&q=site%3Auk+%22what+do+you+want+to+be+when+you+grow+up%22&oq=site%3Auk+%22what+do+you+want+to+be+when+you+grow+up%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...96458.103670..105477...0.0..0.81.492.8......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i71j0i13j0i13i30j0i8i13i30j0i7i30j0i7i5i30.nOZ_TprEOUw), 48,400 and [site:edu](https://www.google.com/search?newwindow=1&ei=7N7TXJG3AYTHwAK98ovwAw&q=site%3Aedu+%22what+do+you+want+to+be+when+you+grow+up%22&oq=site%3Aedu+%22what+do+you+want+to+be+when+you+grow+up%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...33792.34789..35191...0.0..0.66.274.5......0....1..gws-wiz.enm0dDt_14A) 9,740 results.

"*Who* do you want to be when you grow up" refers to personal characteristics, so who do you want to be as a person.

[*What* do you want to be when you grow up](https://www.google.com/search?newwindow=1&ei=EN_TXOwujs3AApuDliA&q=site%3Agov+%22what+do+you+want+to+be+when+you+grow+up%22&oq=site%3Agov+%22what+do+you+want+to+be+when+you+grow+up%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...38164.40290..43403...0.0..0.64.329.6......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i71.ZrYO5f-_v6Q) is also commonly used on more formal (.gov) sites, but [*Who* do you want to be.."](https://www.google.com/search?newwindow=1&ei=d97TXPXaGcHHwQKOq4vgAg&q=site%3Agov+%22who+do+you+want+to+be+when+you+grow+up%22&oq=site%3Agov+%22who+do+you+want+to+be+when+you+grow+up%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...137712.138308..139213...0.0..0.54.158.3......0....1..gws-wiz.0txI5g9eTQo) not really.